# Understanding changing content with responsive web design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been trying to learn how to design web pages using responsive web design. I have come across an interesting example that I do not understand:

http://www.sixty-nine.us/collections/general/

On this page on a desktop you will see gifs but when you shrink the browser enough you will see still images.

I thought this type of change in content was not possible with responsive web design because it can only control the style not the content. I was hoping someone could tell me what is actually happening here, and if my conception of the limitations of responsive web design to not change content is correct.

Comment: Did you look at the page source code?

Answer (score 0):

Any responsive design is based on `@media` CSS queries where you can choose which style should be applied on elements on which screen sizes (CSS approach)

Or using some JS code which monitors window width and shows/hides some elements or does what it should do. (JS approach)

Answer (score 0):

They are actually looping [videos](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0515/5693/t/2/assets/product-video-whatever-dress-black-linen.mp4?7907595077267123575) and not gif. If the resolution is low the video is hidden, and jpg shown using `display:none`. Check the end of their stylesheet: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0515/5693/t/2/assets/legend.css?7907595077267123575

They are using `@media` to control how it is shown on different devices. Read more about `@media` here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Responsive web design is a wide variety of information on the Internet ,and the information is abstract,philosophical,and anecdotal.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, in responsive mode we hide or display content. 
For example: slideshow can be hidden in 480px less screens. for that we display a banner still banner with large text to explain the section / content.

So content can be changed with CSS. But the content does not change or added. Normally content is already loaded. But the showing will be changed with the responsiveness.

PS. your link does not work.